# Check if Doctrine results is NULL or empty or hasn't any records

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Which is the right way to check if Doctrine query result is empty or hasn't values in order to show a message to users? I've this code:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $this->sdriving_emisors = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingEmisor')->createQuery('a')->execute();
}
```

And in my view I'm checking as follow:

```
<?php if (!empty($sdriving_emisors)): ?>
  // show records
<?php else: ?>
  // show message
<?php endif; ?>
```

But doesn't work because `$sdriving_emisors` always has content, so any help?
PS: I'm working with Symfony 1.4.20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The execute() method returns an DoctrineCollection Object. [You can use count()](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Doctrine_Collection.class.html#det_methods_count).

```
public function count(  )
```

> Gets the number of records in this collection
>
> Returns integer

Comment: Also, don't use empty method on variables that are created in the actions. Remember to use $sf_data->getRaw('varname').
Take a look at http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_output_escaping